# One number in each column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, list

I have a question how to put number in each column.
Right now, the data is looking like this.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10 |
| 2 | 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12 |

My goal is making this table look like this below.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

etc.

```
create table pp 
(
 id int,
    toppings int);
insert into pp
(id, toppings) 
values
(1,1),
(1,2),
(1,3),
(1,4),
(1,5),
(1,6),
(1,8),
(1,10),
(2,4),
(2,6),
(2,7),
(2,9),
(2,11),
(2,12);
```

I know this work but I'm looking for an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a, unnest(b) 
from pp;
```

`unnest()` transforms an array into a set of rows.

Here is the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

And here is the [demo](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yxp7zt6s).